# XmlElement HasChildNodes property definition

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

Lets say you have this XML structure:

```
<Class>
       <Worker>
              <Name> Dan </Name>
              <Phone> 123 </Phone> 
                <Class>
                     <Address>
                        <Street> yellow brick road </Street>
                        <Zip Code> 123456 </Zip Code>
                     </Address>
                </Class>
         </Worker>
 </Class>
```

Using `XMLElement`, my problem is that the`HasChildNodes` property of the `<Name>` element returns true, while I would expect it to return false.

`HasChildNodes` by my definition should be like this: `<Worker>` has children, `<Address>` also, but `<Street>` and `<Name>` don't have children, they have a value instead.

How can I differentiate these cases? Is there another property with the behaviour I expect?

Comment: @Downvoter: Don't know the answer but know how to downvote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DOM terms character content is represented as *text nodes*, so only completely empty element nodes (`<foo/>` or `<bar></bar>`) would have no children.  You'll have to check all the child nodes to see whether any of them are `XMLElement`.

Comment: Nice solution, do you know why everything with xml in C#  is so hard and contradict any normal logic.
I need this for recursion so imagine instead of simple end statement what should I do in addition. 
By the way you answered another question of mine I thought about with <foo/>. Thanks

Comment: @JavaSa in this case it isn't C#'s fault - the DOM API interfaces are a (family of) W3C specification(s), designed by committee to be implementable in many different programming languages (Java, .NET, JavaScript, etc.).  Because the DOM is supposed to work the same in all languages it tends to be quite "clunky", not quite fitting the normal idioms in any of them.  Thus alongside the official W3C DOM most languages have alternative models that are more natural to that particular language, e.g. JDOM or XOM in Java.

Comment: @JavaSa ... or [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.haselements.aspx) in C#.

Comment: Another question do you have any idea how to identify `</foo>`, in other words end of `XmlElement`?

Comment: @JavaSa there's no representation of the tags as such in the DOM, it's just an abstract model of the tree structure.  In your example XML in the question the `Class` element is a node with three child nodes, a text node containing the whitespace before the `<Address>` tag, the `Address` element itself, and another text node containing the whitespace between `</Address>` and `</Class>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the "Dan" value inside the `Name` element is treated as a child node.

Perhaps you could test whether the `XMLElement` only has an `XMLText` child, or whether it has no `XMLElement` children?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code in vb.net to check if a node actually has xml child elements

```
Function hasXmlChildElements(ByVal node As XmlNode) As Boolean
            If node.HasChildNodes AndAlso node.ChildNodes.Count = 1 AndAlso node.FirstChild.GetType.Name.ToUpper = "XMLTEXT" Then
                Return False
            End If
            Return node.HasChildNodes
    End Function
```